# Views in CardView container not rendered properly with corner radius

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-cardview

I am developing a player application. I want to show a `CardView` with the cover of the album and the album name. Here is my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:elevation="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/no_cover" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:alpha="0.85"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_light" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

As you can see my `CardView` has corner radius set to `10dp`. On my Nexus 5 running API 22 everything works like a charm but on my older HTC device running API 17, the `ImageView` and the `TextView` have corner radius set to `0`.

[image: API 22]
[image: API 17]

Has anyone experienced such problems? Thanks in advance for the answers!

Comment: android:scaleType="fitXY" should work

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Scale type is related to the content of the `ImageView`. My problem is that the `ImageView` and the `TextView` have corner radius `0` but not the same as the container.

Answer (score 1):

rounded_image.xml

```
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
<stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="#808080" />
<corners 
    android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:topRightRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" />

<padding android:left="2dp" android:top="2dp" android:right="2dp"                  
  android:bottom="2dp" />
```

rounded_textview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
<stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="#808080" />
<corners 
    android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:topRightRadius="0dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" />
```

Your main.xml

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/avatar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/rounded_image" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:alpha="0.85"
    android:background="@drwable/rounded_textview"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Test"
    android:textColor="@color/primary_light" />
```